# Want to Replace Some JavaScript with a String

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have Some Text Like

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer **adipiscing** elit. Donec
>   condimentum pretium nisl. Integer quis tellus nec turpis placerat
>   scelerisque.

And I have a JavaScript Like

```
<script language="javascript1.1"
src="http://www.example.com?id=123&amp;msg=how are you"></script>
```

This Script is also String for me. So how can i replace this JS with **adipiscing**

My Output should be like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer < script language="javascript1.1" src="http://www.example.com?id=123&msg=how are you">< /script> elit. Donec condimentum pretium nisl. Integer quis tellus nec turpis placerat scelerisque.

Please, someone let me know the JavaScript for This Problem.

Comment: sorry, but.. wtf? Why would you do that?

Comment: You want the actual script as a string or the result of the script? - and BTW, `language=` is a deprecated attribute of the script tag.

Comment: wrap your script in the function, then call the function

Comment: i need to refresh some text with dynamically and Load the Script. I have done the Replacing Scripts now i need to know how i can execute the Script Automatically. Any one can give the Solution pls...?

Answer (score 2):

```
var startingText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum pretium nisl. Integer quis tellus nec turpis placerat scelerisque.";

var jsText = "<script language=\"javascript1.1\" src=\"http://www.example.com?id=123&amp;msg=how%20are%20you\"></script>";

var endingText = startingText.replace("adipiscing",jsText);
```

Edit: I was trying to create a jsfiddle to show a working example, but for some reason it's detecting the script tags inside the JS string and refusing to work properly.

Second Edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/JMwQm/

Comment: This answers the question, but still seems like an odd question :)

Answer (score -2):

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('adipiscing', '&amp;lt;script language="javascript1.1" src="http://www.example.com?id=123&amp;msg=how are you"&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;');
```